# aRGB order turns into BGRa when switching from ios sdk 4.0 to ios sdk 4.1?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ios-simulator, rgb

I have a piece of code that loops through every pixel in an image to edit its' aRGB values.

I've been coding up to up to iOS sdk 4.0 and it has been in the order aRGB. Since the release of iOS sdk 4.1, I've downloaded and installed. Now when I choose to run in the simulator with iOS sdk 4.1, the ordering is BGRa! (same as ios sdk 4.2). When I switch back to iOS 4.0, it's aRGB.

Am I going crazy? I would like to support iOS 3.2 and above.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: I remember reading a few weeks ago somewhere in Apple's doc that they switched from aRGB to BGRa. I can't find the page though.

Comment: What do you mean by looping through every pixel in an image? Do you mean you're getting the bytes from a `CGImage` and looping through them? Or something else?